# Visual Studio stops working when running Poisson Surface Reconstruction algorithm

Tags: visual-studio, poisson, 3d-reconstruction

I have downloaded the code of Poisson Surface Reconstruction algorithm from  [this link](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version9.011/) and trying to run it in Visual Studio. But when I debug it, it does not produce any output; rather Visual Studio stops working.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, but the code of Poisson Reconstruction algorithm uses Build Tools 2015 (which are installed on my computer). When I opened the solution file in it, I was asked to upgrade to build tools 2017 and Windows SDK to 10, but I did not upgrade.

Can anyone kindly guide me regarding this issue. I don't know whether there is any problem in Visual Studio or I am debugging it in wrong way. I mean, am I required to pass any command line arguments to it when running? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My "guiding advice" is: [localize the issue yourself first](/help/how-to-ask) by [reducing the code to a minimal one that reproduces the issue](/help/mcve). As it is now, the question is off topic as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336507/questions-about-localizing-a-problem .

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded this project, and DID upgrade it to VS2017/Win10, and it build just fine. If you are expecting some output from the ConsoleApp, you will likely need to modify some command line arguments in the DEBUG config.

The command line args are currently: **--depth 10 --verbose --in \data\pointsets\lucy.tiny.bnpts**

**Build Output:**

1>------ Build started: Project: PoissonRecon, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

1>PoissonRecon.cpp

1>[WARNING] Setting default full depth to 5

1>PlyFile.cpp

1>MarchingCubes.cpp

1>[WARNING] Not clear if MarchingSquares::edgeMask and MarchingSquares::edges are set correctly

1>Geometry.cpp

1>Factor.cpp

1>CmdLineParser.cpp

1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification

1>Generating code

1>Finished generating code

1>PoissonRecon.vcxproj -> F:\Users\Ryzen\Downloads\PoissonRecon\PoissonRecon\Bin\x64\Debug\PoissonRecon.exe

1>Done building project "PoissonRecon.vcxproj".

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========